# colour inside a zapf dingbats letter

Tags: color, backgrounds, letters

I would like the "1" being of the colour of the background (i.e., yellow!10).
But actually I get the thin lines within the "one" when using the TikZ code below.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[yellow!10] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (2,2);
\node at (1,1) {\Large{\color{red}\ding{202}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4):

If we insert `\ding{202}` inside a node even if we add `inner sep=0pt` a little space appear on the edges of the symbol, here an example

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [yellow!10] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\draw [step=1cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (2,2);
\node [text=red,font=\Large,inner sep=0pt,fill=yellow!10,circle,draw]at (1,1) {\ding{202}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can bypass this problem with a negative `inner sep`, just manual adjustments

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill [yellow!10] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\draw [step=1cm,gray,very thin] (0,0) grid (2,2);
\node [text=red,font=\Large,inner sep=-1.8pt,fill=yellow!10,circle]at (1,1) {\ding{202}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The fix works well for me since I have only numbers from 1 to 9, but what if one has also letters like for instance a, b, p, q.

Comment: @NicolasBeldiceanu Why would that be any different?

Comment: It may be different since the dingbats numbers have a shape that is a circle, so using a circle in the background is fine; but with letters whose shape is not a circle, using a circle may not work.